# Best way to add values to a nested named list

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list named list which looks like:

```
Browse[2]> rr
[[1]]
[[1]]$parameter
[1] 6

[[1]]$statistic
[1] 13.73371

[[1]]$observed
[1] 63


[[2]]
[[2]]$parameter
[1] 9

[[2]]$statistic
[1] 12.7092

[[2]]$observed
[1] 41
```

The `dput` output:

```
list(list(parameter = 6, statistic = 13.7337141468157, observed = 63L), 
    list(parameter = 9, statistic = 12.7092009771629, observed = 41L), 
)
```

And I have another list of doubles which looks like:

```
Browse[2]> conf_intervals[1, ]
 [1]   6.592301   8.236966  16.109724   6.629236  15.896665   2.606493  12.970584   5.213050   6.216172  62.650545  12.291587 156.140508
[13]  63.080242  41.772004   1.585398   8.012596  13.538332  17.923161  10.254139   5.857182   7.312259  11.952349  16.303510   6.344661
[25]   1.510251   1.325398  13.766738   2.625461   4.490282  37.430535   9.891200 161.666251 143.450382  65.561283   2.535526   5.749675
[37]  31.575314  22.625427   6.825213
```

The `dput`output:

```
c(6.59230092348831, 8.23696562071911, ..... )
```

I want to add the values from my second list to the nested list with a new name. I want the final output to be like:

```
Browse[2]> rr
[[1]]
[[1]]$parameter
[1] 6

[[1]]$statistic
[1] 13.73371

[[1]]$observed
[1] 63

[[1]]$lower
[1] 6.592301


[[2]]
[[2]]$parameter
[1] 9

[[2]]$statistic
[1] 12.7092

[[2]]$observed
[1] 41

[[2]]$lower
[1] 8.236966
```

Is there an easy way to do this without doing an explicit loop over the nested list?

Comment: There is no 41 value in your second list. Currently, there is no clear rule regarding how values from the second list should be assigned to elements of the first list. Also, provide the output of `dput(rr)` and `dput(conf_intervals[1, ])`.

Comment: @Roland I have added the dput output. The `41` value is the `$observed` value for the 2nd element in both the lists.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like that could help? ...

```
list1 <- list(
    parameter=5,
    statistics=13,
    observed=63
)
list2 <- list(list1,list1)
list3 <- list(c(1,2))

for(i in seq(length(list2))){
    list2[[i]]["conf"] <- list3[[1]][i]
}
```

which results in the following list

```
list(list(parameter = 5, statistics = 13, observed = 63, conf = 1), 
    list(parameter = 5, statistics = 13, observed = 63, conf = 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
rr <- list(list(parameter = 6, statistic = 13.7337141468157, observed = 63L), 
           list(parameter = 9, statistic = 12.7092009771629, observed = 41L)
)
conf <- c(6.59230092348831, 8.23696562071911)

DF <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, rr)
DF$conf <- conf

#if you need a nested list:
split(DF, seq_len(nrow(DF)))

#or if you don't like class data.frame
lapply(split(DF, seq_len(nrow(DF))), as.list)
```